# How to validate before saving and throw checked exception

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following scenario:

- There's a user repository which can save/update a user
- I want to validate the user's firstname/lastname (perform some string operations) before saving/updating
- If the user's firstname/lastname is < 2 character after having performed the operations, a checked custom `UnacceptableStringValueException` should be thrown

Note that many services access the user repository, so it's cumbersome to implement new logic directly before saving.

What I tried to do in order to perform the validation just before saving/updating without having to implement this for every save/update call explicitly, is to use a JPA listener. Using `@PrePersist` and `@PreUpdate` 
 I achieved the goal of performing the validation before each save/update.
However there are two problems with this solution:

- The checked exception is not enforced on the methods which save/update a user and the exception gets automatically wrapped as a `RuntimeException` via the listener
- When trying to use AOP to catch said `RuntimeException` and unpack the original checked exception, I keep getting `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only`

Note that a simple service layer performing the check before saving/updating the user won't solve my use case because there's a user role repository which could also save/update a user (`@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`)

What's a good way to solve the constraints described in the scenario on top?

Comment: You can check/validate fields values by using java feature and if else condition in controller/service layer. And throw specific message by using custom exception class. refer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56832667/how-to-pass-api-exception-output-to-through-own-rest-service)

Comment: Why not simply use Bean Validation on your entity fields, though? It integrates with JPA nicely and will work whenever you save/update the entity, whatever the method

Comment: @crizzis the validation should take place after the string operations were performed (such as trimming)

Comment: Bean validation is invoked about the same time as the pre persist callback

Comment: @crizzis thanks for the hint, unfortunately I need to dynamically load the allowed size from a config file, I'm not aware if that's compatible with bean validation

Comment: You can do that by implementing a custom validator. With Hibernate Validator, you can even register a custom validator for existing annotations, as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_constraint_definitions_via_code_serviceloader_code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a somewhat viable solution by fixing the `org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only` error.

The problem was, that the checked exception caused an unexpected rollback, in order to fix this, I added my custom checked exception to the exceptions which can be rolled back like this: `@Transactional(rollbackFor = {UnacceptableStringValueException.class})`